# How to see if an array is contained in a column?

Tags: arrays, vba

I am looking for a vba code for finding out if an array of strings is contained(not totally matched) in the cells of a column. I have a list of fake emails stored in a sheet and in another sheet i have the list of emails I want to check. If an email from the first list is found in the 2nd column i need the row to be coloured in yellow.
Here is what i have:

```
Dim list As String, c As Range, count As Long, total As Long
count = 1
total = Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For ix = 1 To total
list = Worksheets("Helper").Range("A" & counter).Value
k = "a" & count
    For Each c In Worksheets("JP").Range(k)
        c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255
    Next c
End If
End If
count = count + 1
Next ix
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string is contained within another you would do so using

```
If InStr(1, str, substr, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
    ' put logic for when substr is within str
End If
```

which will return a positive number of the substr is found anywhere within str.

For your specific application I would work on debugging your loop, it looks like you are on the right track